# How does ISet have two Add(T item) methods that vary only by return type?

Tags: c#, collections

I know I can't overload a return type (I think I know this).

```
void F()
{
}

bool F()
{
   return true;
}
```

..produces error `already defines a member called 'F' with the same parameter types`

However, I'm reading the [documentation for ISet from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22SYSTEM.COLLECTIONS.GENERIC.ISET%601%22%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true), and I think I see the two Add methods that only vary by return type.

What is going on here?

Comment: thanks for the answers, i'll randomly pick one to mark as the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first "Add" method is actually `ICollection<T>.Add`, which is inherited.

When this is implemented in a class, at least one of the two `Add` methods will need to be explicitly implemented, ie:

```
void ICollection<T>.Add(T item)
{
   // ... Implement here
```

Comment: just curious, you say "implemented in a class" - is that as opposed to implemented in a struct?

Comment: @Gabriel No - implemented in any type.  That being said, a struct implementing `ISet<T>` would be **very** inappropriate. ;)  It doesn't fit any of the suggested requirements for a struct, as it'd be >16 bytes, mutable, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The other `Add` method is an [explicitly implemented interface method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

When an interface method is implemented explicitly, it cannot be called without casting the reference to the interface type first, which makes calls unambiguous, and therefore having multiple methods with the same signature is fine.

To do this in your code, you'd do, for instance

```
class MyCollection<T> : ICollection<T> {
    public void Add() { ... }
    void ICollection<T>.Add() { ... }
}
```

This avoids having to come up with alternate method names to avoid collisions with interface names, when you'd like the interface method to do something slightly differently than the other method.

Comment: Saying that the other Add method is an explicitly implemented interface method is wrong. Explicitly *implemented* interface method can only ever appear in a class/struct and the never can appear on an interface, since interfaces can't have *implementation* outside of a class/struct. Both methods that you are mentioning are interface methods, one on ISet and the other is on ICollection, and neither of them are explicitly implemented interface method when we are not mentioning classes that implement these interfaces, which you did not. Perhaps you could use better wording.

Comment: @zespri: You are right. I didn't look at the page properly and didn't notice that it was an interface and not a class. You should post your comment as an answer, because there's obviously a difference between interfaces and classes here.

Answer (score 3):

Interface methods can be implemented explicitly, like so:

```
public class Something : IINterface1, IInterface2
{
    public bool DoSomething();
    public void IInterface2.DoSomething();
}
```

Now the method returning `void` is only accessable if you cast the class to the interface:

```
Something s = new Something();
IInterface2 i = (IInterface2)s;
i.DoSomething(); // method returning void
```